# Using regEx to remove digits from string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove all digits from a string that are not attached to a word. Examples:

```
 "python 3" => "python"
 "python3" => "python3"
 "1something" => "1something"
 "2" => ""
 "434" => ""
 "python 35" => "python"
 "1 " => ""
 " 232" => ""
```

Till now I am using the following regular expression:

`((?<=[ ])[0-9]+(?=[ ])|(?<=[ ])[0-9]+|^[0-9]$)`

which can correctly do some of the examples above, but not all. Any help and some explanation?

Comment: Wait, why `"1something" => "something"`?

Comment: Thanks, u are right! corrected it.

Comment: Why not just search for ( \d+ ) and remove it?

Comment: cause it will remove the attached digits.

Comment: I managed a solution without using reg exp. But I would like to see the reg exp solution.

Comment: How do you want to treat something like "py27thon"

Comment: Your code is removing spaces yet your accepted regex solution is not so what do you actually want?

Comment: I am not sure what u mean. In the accepted answer it is mentioned to use `strip`.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris. strip does not remove spaces from the middle of a string. Do you really want potentially huge amounts of continuous whitespace in your returned string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use word boundaries?

```
\b\d+\b
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> import re
>>> words = ['python 3', 'python3', '1something', '2', '434', 'python 35', '1 ', ' 232']
>>> for word in words:
...     print("'{}' => '{}'".format(word, re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', '', word)))
...
'python 3' => 'python '
'python3' => 'python3'
'1something' => '1something'
'2' => ''
'434' => ''
'python 35' => 'python '
'1 ' => ' '
' 232' => ' '
```

Note that this will not remove spaces before and after. I would advise using `strip()`, but if not you can probably do `\b\d+\b\s*` (for space after) or something similar.

Comment: Just a word of warning I think this, \b\d+\b, will match if you have something like this "python-3" or "python_3", this may be what you want but its worth noting.

Comment: @milo.farrell Yes for `-` but not for an underscore.

Answer (score 3):

You could just split the words and remove any words that are digits which is a lot easier to read:

```
new = " ".join([w for w in s.split() if not w.isdigit()])
```

And also seems faster:

```
In [27]: p = re.compile(r'\b\d+\b')

In [28]: s =  " ".join(['python 3', 'python3', '1something', '2', '434', 'python
    ...:  35', '1 ', ' 232'])

In [29]: timeit " ".join([w for w in s.split() if not w.isdigit()])

100000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 µs per loop

In [30]: timeit p.sub('', s)

100000 loops, best of 3: 3.34 µs per loop
```

It also removes the space like your expected output:

```
In [39]:  re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', '', " 2")
Out[39]: ' '

In [40]:  " ".join([w for w in " 2".split() if not w.isdigit()])
Out[40]: ''

In [41]:  re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', '', s)
Out[41]: 'python  python3 1something   python     '

In [42]:  " ".join([w for w in s.split() if not w.isdigit()])
Out[42]: 'python python3 1something python'
```

So both approaches are significantly different.

Comment: The OP mentioned in a comment that he has a solution without regexp already. (But yes, this is definitely the best way)

Comment: @brianpck, the OP also wants `"1 "` to become  `""` which this does and also more efficiently so I will leave the answer as it is a better overall approach for future readers and the fact it does the correct thing that the OP seems to want.

Comment: actually, you could just pass the generator into `join` instead of creating a list: `" ".join(w for w in s.split() if not w.isdigit())`

Comment: @Bahrom, that is slower as python will build a list internally if you pass a generator,

Comment: @Bahrom, some comparisons here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2141635, join has to do two passes over the data, one to check the size needed and one to create the new string. Because you can only iterate a generator once, it first has to be converted a list.

Comment: Thanks, will check that out!

Answer (score 0):

This regex, (\s|^)\d+(\s|$), could work as shown below in javascript

```js
var value = "1 3@bar @foo2 * 112";
var matches = value.replace(/(\s|^)\d+(\s|$)/g,"");
console.log(matches)
```

It works in 3 parts:

1. It first matches a space or begging of string using (\s|^) with \s matching a white-space | meaning or and ^ meaning beginning of string.
2. next matching digits from 1 to times using \d for a digit and + to match 1 to N times but as many as possible.
3. Finally (\s|$) matches a space or end of sting with \s matching space, | meaning or, and $ matching end of string.

You can replace $ with end of line or \n if you have several lines or just add it in next to it like this (\s|$|\n). Hope this is what your're looking for.

Comment: This will match double spaces