# Remove digits from a list of strings in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, string, digits

I have this pandas dataframe

```
0  Tokens 
1: 'rice', 'XXX', '250g'
2: 'beer', 'XXX', '750cc'
```

All tokens here, 'rice', 'XXX' and '250g' are in the same list of strings, also in the same column

I want to remove the digits, and because it with another words,
the digits cannot be removed.

I have tried this code:

```
def remove_digits(tokens):
    """
    Remove digits from a string
    """
    return [''.join([i for i in tokens if not i.isdigit()])]

df["Tokens"] = df.Tokens.apply(remove_digits)
df.head()
```

but it only joined the strings, and I clearly do not want to do that.

My desired output:

```
0  Tokens
1: 'rice' 'XXX' 'g'
2: 'beer', 'XXX', 'cc'
```

Comment: What is `Tokens` here? Could you provide the sentences to construct the df?

Comment: It is the column where my cleaned tokens are.

Comment: I think this answers your question by using regular expressions:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178364/using-regex-to-remove-digits-from-string

Comment: In your suggested solution, you are passing a list `Tokens` to your function, you need to then loop to each caracther in the string `i` before applying `isdigit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tokens':[['rice', 'XXX', '250g'], 
                             ['beer', 'XXX', '750cc']]})

def remove_digits_from_string(s):
    return ''.join([x for x in s if not x.isdigit()])

def remove_digits(l):
    return [remove_digits_from_string(s) for s in l]

df["Tokens"] = df.Tokens.apply(remove_digits)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using pandas methods, which are vectorised so more efficient that looping.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Tokens": [["rice", "XXX", "250g"], ["beer", "XXX", "750cc"]]})

col = "Tokens"
df[col] = (
    df[col]
    .explode()
    .str.replace("\d+", "", regex=True)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(list)
)
#             Tokens
# 0   [rice, XXX, g]
# 1  [beer, XXX, cc]
```

Here we use:

- [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to convert the Series of lists into rows
- [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace occurrences of `\d` (number 0-9) with `""` (nothing)
- [`pandas.Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to group the Series by index (`level=0`) and put them back into lists (`.agg(list)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) + [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) in order to update your original dataframe.

```
import re

for index, lst in enumerate(df['Tokens'].to_list()):
  lst = [re.sub('\d+', '', i) for i in lst]
  df.loc[index, 'Tokens'] = lst

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Tokens
0   [rice, XXX, g]
1   [beer, XXX, cc]
```